# How to prove $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ with respect to the metric of $\mathscr{C}(X)$ if and only if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on X?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is a restatement of Theorem 7.9 in Rudin. I have been able to prove it if X is compact, but I just can't figure out how to show it for an arbitrary domain X. The proof I have is as follows:

Note that the metric in question is:

$d(f, g) = ||f - g|| = \sup_{x \in X} |f - g|$

**Proof:**
Assume that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly. Then $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $|f_n - f| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Note that since $[a, b]$ is compact, we have that $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| = \max_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|$. So by choosing N large, we can guarantee that $\max_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| < \varepsilon$, which means that that $d(f_n, f) \rightarrow 0$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Now assume that $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| = \max_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then $\left| \max_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| - 0 \right| < \varepsilon$ for $n > N$. Now we note that
\begin{equation*}
\left| f_n - f \right| \leq \max_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| \leq |\max_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|| < \varepsilon
\end{equation*}
and we have $|f_n - f| < \varepsilon$ as desired. $\blacksquare$

I believe that my proof rests on the fact that $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| = \max_{x \in [a,b]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|$, although looking at it now I am uncertain. Would this proof work for a non compact set, or what?

Comment: I do not understand what did you gain by having "max" instead of "sup"? Why would it matter that the sup is attained?

Comment: Now that I am looking at it, I am actually not quite so sure where my confusion came in. Perhaps by typing it up it became more clear. Now I feel quite foolish for rushing to post.